# Where can Firefox store cached flash (.flv) video files?

Tags: firefox, flv

I am willing to save an online flash video (`.flv`) file for further offline watching. I couldn't download this particular video file through a direct link (grabbed with Video Download Helper extension) because of a very slow and unresponsive server, but I could watch it to the end with a webpage embedded player, and now it is for sure saved to cache (as I can rewind it and watch from any place without no more waiting).

I went to

> /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/a0zzqdg4.default/Cache

But the file I want is not there (it is to be about 200 MiBs, but the biggest file there is of 22 MiBs and is called "_CACHE_003_").

Where might it be if not in the standard cache directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is there or in /tmp;

Nowadays, Flash Player (starting from some 10.xx version) for linux does `unlink` on flv files;

`ls -la /proc/{PID OF PLAYER PLUGIN}/fd` to get an idea;

More info (check the script): http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/linux/104420/

Answer (score 2):

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp

Also reachable through WIN+R, then typing %appdata% and then following Local -> Temp.

Comment: OP's not a Windows user.

Comment: Sorry, good catch. I should have read the question better. I'll leave it, in case anyone stumbles across this question looking for an answer from a windows perspective. The OP can use the following URL: "about:cache" to see the default and alternative cache addresses on his system.

Comment: I think this shows the clue anyway. From your answer I can figure out that Firefox uses a user's common temporary files directory alongside with its profile cache.

Answer (score 1):

The OP was looking for a linux solution, but the question is valid for Windows too, so here's an answer for that. Look for `fla*.tmp` in

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\acro_rd_dir
```

Also reachable through <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then typing `%temp%`, or following [Paul's example](https://superuser.com/a/216490/16966):`%appdata%` and then following to *Local -> Temp*.

Chances are you won't be able to do anything with the files though because they'll be marked as locked or in use. There are a few programs that can work around this for you, just search for "windows copy locked or in-use file" and variations thereof. The ones worth their salt will probably use Volume Shadow Service (VSS). I like [hobocopy](http://candera.github.com/hobocopy/) and here's an example use:

```
hobocopy.exe /verbosity=2 %temp%\acro_rd_dir D:\Playback\Incoming flaFF7E.tmp
pushd D:\Playback\Incoming
move /y flaFF7E.tmp SomeUsefulName.flv
explorer /select,%cd%\SomeUsefulName.flv
```

The relevant part is `hobocopy source_dir destination_dir file-to-copy`, and the rest sugar. Replace *explorer...* with `start %cd%\SomeUsefulName.flv` to start playing the video right away instead of just selecting it.

Recipe last tested with Firefox 18 on Window 7.

Answer (score -1):

Run `locate *.flv` to see all your flv files on your system.

However you might need to run `sudo updatedb` first (to update locate command index database)

Comment: Firefox strips names and extensions of the files it puts in cache, so I suppose looking for *.flv won't help much. Looking for FLV in files contents with a rich search tool of a kind (like Midnight Commander) perhaps...

Answer (score -2):

I think it is better to use WinRAR and go to `C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5` OR `\Low\Content.IE5`. Then look in each of the folders and look for the biggest file, probably ending in `.flv` or `.avi`.